# How to run GDB with the results of a script?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb

Simple, maybe not so simple issue. How can I run GDB with the results of a script?

What I mean is that instead of saying:

```
run arg1
```

You would say:

```
run "python generatingscript.py"
```

which would output the args. I'm aware I could find a way to do this by sleeping the program after run the args from the command line, but it would be really darn convenient if there was a way to do this kind of thing directly in gdb.

Just for context, my use case is a situation where I writing crash test cases that look like long strings of hex data. Putting them in by hand at the command line isn't the most convenient thing.

Comment: What operating system? If you have one with a Unix shell, try `(gdb) run $(python generatingscript.py)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb with the `--args` option like this: `gdb --args your_program $(python generatingscript.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use bash to generate an output file

```
$python generatingscript.py > testinput
```

then in gdb

```
gdb$ run < testinput
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for my ubuntu machine which deploys "<<<" instead of "<".

> `(gdb) r <<< $(python  exploit.py )`